Positive definite matrices and pivots.
I found these lecture notes online about positive definite matrices.
To summarise what's needed for my question, they give 4 ways of working out if a matrix is positive definite. In particular, it says A matrix is positive definite if it’s symmetric and all its pivots are positive.
I hadn't known that definition before, but I tested it on the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ which I know is not positive definite as its eigenvalues aren't all positive (+ 1 and -1). But its pivots are positive (both 1). Is the pivot definition correct? I'm unsure if I'm working out the pivots correctly, I did it by swapping the rows to get it to Row Echelon form.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \

\frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \
1 & 0 \
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 0 \
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \
\end{array}
\right)
$$


meanwhile, the notes you linked do not define the word "pivot"  and the meaning is not the usual

@WillJagy sorry, what calculation are you doing? Is that to work out the pivots

see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
